# Auth data resets whenever App is rebuild in Flutter

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, flutter-dependencies

I have an Auth method setup that extends ChangeNotifier to give login and store tokens and other details.

and in my main.dart file I am calling a multi provider to get all providers, inside multi provider I have a Consumer as a child which decides which page to call as default. i.e if auth.isAuth returns true then MainPage.dart will be called or AuthScreen.dart.

Login works fine and everything else works fine.

But the issue which I am facing is, Whenever is reload or rebuild my application the auth data becomes null.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

main.dart

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Auth(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Cart(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: AddressBook(Auth().token),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Orders(),
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer<Auth>(
        builder: (ctx, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
          title: 'APP NAME',
          theme: ThemeData(
              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
              primaryColor: Colors.white,
              primaryColorDark: Colors.white,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white),
          home: auth.isAuth ? MainPage() : AuthScreen(),
          routes: {
            MainPage.routeName: (ctx) => MainPage(),
            CartScreen.routeName: (ctx) => CartScreen(),
            OrderScreen.routeName: (ctx) => OrderScreen(),
            EditAddressScreen.routeName: (ctx) => EditAddressScreen(),
          }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

auth.dart

```
class Auth extends ChangeNotifier {

  String _token;
  String _refresh_token;
  DateTime _expiryDate;
  int _userId;

  bool get isAuth {
    return _token != null;
  }

  String get token {
    if (_expiryDate != null &&
        _expiryDate.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        _token != null) {
      return _token;
    }
    return null;
  }

  int get userId {
    return _userId;
  }

  Future<void> _authenticate(String email, String password, String urlSegment) async {
    final url = 'http://192.168.1.120:8080/oauth/token';
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {'grant_type': 'password', 'username': email, 'password': password};
    var parts = [];
    parts.add('${Uri.encodeQueryComponent("grant_type")}=${Uri.encodeQueryComponent("password")}');
    parts.add('${Uri.encodeQueryComponent("username")}=${Uri.encodeQueryComponent(email)}');
    parts.add('${Uri.encodeQueryComponent("password")}=${Uri.encodeQueryComponent(password)}');
    var formData = parts.join('&');
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: formData,
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        }
      );
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      print(response.statusCode);
      if(response.statusCode != 200){
        throw HttpException(responseData['error']['error_description']);
      }else{
        _token = responseData['access_token'];
        _userId = responseData['customerId'];
        _refresh_token = responseData['refresh_token'];
        _expiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
          Duration(
            seconds: responseData['expires_in'],
          ),
        );
        notifyListeners();
      }
      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
       throw HttpException(responseData['error']['error_description']);
      }

    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  Future<void> signup(String email, String password) async {
    return _authenticate(email, password, 'signUp');
  }

  Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
    return _authenticate(email, password, 'signInWithPassword');
  }
  
}
```

Comment: To expose a newly created object, use the default constructor of a provider. Do not use the .value constructor if you want to create an object, or you may otherwise have undesired side-effects. Using changeNotifierprovider.value is completely wrong.

Comment: can u guide me what how iam supposed to used all the providers.

Comment: Remove the .value and use create: (_)=> , instead of value and see if that works

Comment: did what u said but no luck.. still redirect to AuthScreen.

Comment: i did noticed that when i removes the multiprovider and use a single ChangeNotifierProvider for auth. it works fine and mainpage.dart loads instead of authscreen.dart

Comment: Did the auth state remain persistence even after rebuilding the whole app ? What I mean is , is the user navigates to mainPage instead of the authPage when the app is rebuild ?

Comment: Actually, I have fixed the issue.. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it looks like you are storing OAuth tokens in memory, so they are dropped upon every restart, and this provides poor usability.

**MOBILE TOKEN STORAGE**

OAuth tokens can be saved to secure encrypted storage to improve usability, perhaps using [this Flutter library](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage). The encryption used should be private to your app, so that no other app can use the tokens.

**STRUCTURING YOUR CODE**

I quite like how you've structured your code, where the rest of the app just calls Auth.dart's **getToken** method when calling a Web API. It looks like your Auth.dart source file needs to do more work to resolve your problem.

**EXAMPLE OF MINE**

This code is in Swift and uses a different flow, with AppAuth libraries. However, the general design pattern can be applied in any language, including Flutter.

- [Token Storage Module](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.ios/blob/master/Source/Plumbing/OAuth/TokenStorage.swift)
- [OAuth Interface used by the rest of the App](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.ios/blob/master/Source/Plumbing/OAuth/Authenticator.swift)
- [OAuth Implementation uses Token Storage](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.ios/blob/master/Source/Plumbing/OAuth/AuthenticatorImpl.swift)
- [API Client that calls GetToken](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.ios/blob/master/Source/Api/Client/ApiClient.swift)
- [View that Calls an API](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.ios/blob/master/Source/Views/Companies/CompaniesViewModel.swift)